# What is wrong in this c++ code?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Why does this code compile and work properly

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    unsigned short int myInt = 99;
    unsigned short int * pMark = 0;
    cout << myInt << endl;
    pMark = &myInt;
    *pMark = 11;
    cout << "*pMark:\t" << *pMark << "\nmyInt:\t" << myInt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When this one doesn't compile:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int addnumber(int *p, int *q){
    cout << *p = 12  << endl;
    cout << *q  = 14 << endl;   
}

int main()
{
    int i , j;
    cout << "enter the value of first number";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "enter the value of second number";
    cin >> j;
    addnumber(&i, &j);
    cout << i << endl;
    cout << j << endl;
}
```

In both the code snippets, I am assigning `*pointer=somevalue`. In the first code, it does not cause an error, but in the second, it causes error in the line

```
cout << *p = 12  << endl;
cout << *q  = 14 << endl;
```

What mistake I am making?

Comment: Regardless of how to massage the syntax to not error, put assignments clearly on their own line, otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `cout << *p = 12 << endl;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

To the compiler, your statement looks like

```
(cout << *p) = (12  << endl);
```